# How can I model webservice and/or Oracle DB?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning MVC. There are plenty of sample codes working with SQL Server. The coder has the database created on the fly from his/her classes, which enables a very clean and rapid development workflow.

I'm working with Oracle DB.
Can I also abstract data from tables, that I already have? I don't need to abstract all columns(i.e. i need only two of 50). I need only read access and wanna use either web service or oracle as input.

You know any sample code, so I can see how can abstract data for web-service or oracle as data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at [`Entity Framework`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). It allows you to abstract your data access code from the underlying database. This really is not MVC specific and you could use it in any .NET application you wish.

As far as web services are concerned I would recommend you designing a data access layer that will be called from your MVC controllers and which would delegate the calls to the underlying web service. An abstraction over this web service would be beneficial if you want to unit test your controllers in isolation.